# TabControl unobvious behavior

Tags: silverlight, tabcontrol

I've added some tabs with the templates into the tabcontrol:

```
<sdk:TabControl x:Name="TabControl">
    <sdk:TabItem Header="Header1" Content="{Binding Path=Content}">
        <sdk:TabItem.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="Header1" Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </sdk:TabItem.ContentTemplate>
    </sdk:TabItem>
    <sdk:TabItem Header="Header2" Content="{Binding Path=Content}">
        <sdk:TabItem.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="Header2" Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </sdk:TabItem.ContentTemplate>
    </sdk:TabItem>
    <sdk:TabItem Header="Header3" Content="{Binding Path=Content}">
        <sdk:TabItem.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="Header3" Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </sdk:TabItem.ContentTemplate>
    </sdk:TabItem>
</sdk:TabControl>
```

If I switch between tabs I see only "Header1" in all tabs and Loaded event fires only once. I expected to see Header1, Header2 and Header3 in the appropriate tabs and to handle 3 loaded events.

I've decompiled the code of the TabControl and there i've found such method:

```
private void UpdateSelectedContent(object content)
{
    TabItem selectedItem = this.SelectedItem as TabItem;
    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        ContentPresenter contentHost = this.GetContentHost(this.TabStripPlacement);
        if (contentHost != null)
        {
            contentHost.HorizontalAlignment = selectedItem.HorizontalContentAlignment;
            contentHost.VerticalAlignment = selectedItem.VerticalContentAlignment;
            contentHost.ContentTemplate = selectedItem.ContentTemplate;
            contentHost.Content = content;
        }
    }
}
```

Seems like if i change the tab contenttemplate switches with it. But the behavior is different.

What is happening here? Why my expectations are wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The UpdateSelectedContent method you reference doesn't set the titles or the loaded handlers. Just specify them in as attributes of the TabItems.

```
 <sdk:TabItem Header="Header 1" Loaded="Tab1_Loaded">
```

etc

Comment: Titles are ok. Content doesn't change.

Comment: Yes.I don't need to handle when the whole tab is loaded. I need to handle content creation. But it doesn't create. Same content in all three tabs.